# How do I output a line in .py working in atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have a working website using python, html, and javascript. I run the application from the app.py file but here's my question. If I were to type print('variable') in one of my .py files, where can I see the output? For debugging purposes.. thx.

Comment: dont use print, use [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Comment: 1, As @avigil mentioned use logging instead of print
2. To really answer your question you will see the print output in the terminal where your `app.py` is running